# Error when running the ruby ​/ rails build in open shift 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, openshift-3

Error when running the ruby ​​/ rails build in open shift 3.

I used my project on openshift 2 and it worked. Try cooloca on openshift 3 and this error happened.

I used the test project and it also did not work. I am using ruby ​​2.4 and rails 5.

Follow the log:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


current directory: /opt/app-root/src/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
Running autoreconf for libffi
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
configure.ac:376: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:349: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:376: the top level
configure.ac:376: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:349: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:376: the top level
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
configure.ac:376: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:349: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:376: the top level
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:376: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:349: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:376: the top level
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:7636: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LD
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
make: ***
["/opt/app-root/src/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a]
Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/opt/app-root/src/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21 for inspection.
Results logged to
/opt/app-root/src/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ffi-1.9.21/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.21'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your system has `autoconf` installed without `libtool`. I can tell because the error message says you are not using `libtool`, but forces `autoconf` to run anyways.

```
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
```

As you might expect, the solution is to install `libtool`. This can be done using apt by running the following commands.

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/607).

For me this issue was solved by installing `libffi` as described [here](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/611#issuecomment-364621532).

On ubuntu this is as easy as

`sudo apt install libffi-dev`

on Fedora the following works:

`sudo dnf install libffi-devel`